# Can't understand error log for Android app using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, error-log

Can anyone please elaborate me about these error log entries:

```
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.Alerts.toast(Alerts.java:14)
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.SalesHandler.startStalesSync(SalesHandler.java:31)
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.Start.act(Start.java:55)
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.Start.onCreate(Start.java:23)
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.Alerts.toast(Alerts.java:14)
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.HttpCall.onPostExecute(HttpCall.java:103)
W/System.err(8537):     at com.any.sales.HttpCall.onPostExecute(HttpCall.java:22)
```

My app keeps on crashing and ADB log is not showing any other error log except this. And I am unable to understand what these entries are trying to say.

I am making an app which Http classes like HttpPost, HttpClient, HttpResponse to connect to an online server and fetch data. I have make a class HttpCall for this purpose and extends AsyncTask. I am using this class since a while, and it was working perfectly with all my projects, but now somehow it is not working properly.

I am doing printStackTrace for the Exception and all I see the entries for error logs. I can rectify the problem if I can understand what these entries are trying to tell. As you can see they are just reference of function name, class name line numbers, no other message to tell that what the error is actually. This is my HttpCall Class:

```
public class HttpCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
String url;
List<NameValuePair> params;
AsyncResponse delegate = null;

public HttpCall(String url, List<NameValuePair> params, AsyncResponse responseDelegate) {
    this.url = url;
    this.params = params;
    this.delegate = responseDelegate;
}

private String post(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Data Objects
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
    HttpPost post;
    HttpClient client;
    HttpResponse response;
    BufferedReader reader;
    StringBuilder builder;
    String line;

    try {
        // Set Parameters
        entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);

        // Set Request
        post = new HttpPost(url);
        post.setEntity(entity);

        // Execute Request through Http Client and Store the response
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        response = client.execute(post);

        // Read Response to the buffer
        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()
                )
        );
        builder = new StringBuilder("");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return builder.toString();
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "Unable to process request"
                + "\nDue to a very slow or no active Internet"
                + "\nPlease try again in few seconds..";
    } catch (NoHttpResponseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "No Response from Server. Please try again in few seconds..";
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "Error in IO";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "Unknown Connection Error";
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        return post(this.url, this.params);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (delegate != null)
            delegate.onFinish(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Alerts.toast(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

This is my AsyncResponse class for to execute in onPostExecute of AsyncTask

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
void onFinish(String output);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. Funny thing it's not related to any thing like Http or Async. This time I was calling a toast not by using `Toast.makeText` but by using new Toast() and this was throwing an exception.

Strange thing is that `printStackTrace` is not showing about this.